# Importing Volley into Activity, particularly Request.Method.POST not being recognized

Tags: android, import, request, android-volley

I am having zero troubles after importing volley classes into my MainActivity except for Request.Method.POST is not being recognized by the

> import com.android.volley.Request.Method;

... I don't know why the import isn't recognizing that single request but my code won't compile until I can get that import to recognize this.

Usage of the Request.Method.POST

> ```
> JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, showUrl, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {...}
> ```

Thanks

Comment: does it give you an error or does not see it at all?

Comment: Try the following `JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, showUrl,null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {...}`

Comment: you only need `import com.android.volley.Request;` instead of `import com.android.volley.Request.Method;`

Comment: Turns out I accidentally imported another method that ended in .Request and the IDE was getting confused on which one to use.